# identifier "fill_vector" is undefinded and im not sure why

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
int miniVector<T>::fill_vector(miniVector<T> &obj)
{
    int numofelements;
    cout << "For how many objects do you want to enter value<s>? ";
    cin >> numofelements;
    obj.resize(numofelements);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numofelements; i++)
    {
        cin >> obj[i];
        obj.push_back(i);
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    miniVector<int> v;
    cout << "int vector: " << endl;
    //fill_vector();
    int sizearray;
    sizearray = fill_vector<int>(v);
    sizearray = v.size();
    //display_vector(v, sizearray);
    return 0;
}
```

Was wonder why i keep getting an error message idnetifier "fill_vector is undefined.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: `fill_vector` is defined as a member function, so it'd need to be `v.fill_vector(&v)` (which points to the fact that passing the `miniVector` as a parameter doesn't make a lot of sense).

Comment: It would be helpful to see the relevant parts of miniVector's definition...

Answer (score 0):

fill_vector is a member function of class miniVector. Thus you have to specify an object for which the member function is called in this statement (if the member function is non-static) or class name (if the member function is static)

```
sizearray = fill_vector<int>(v);
```

This call is wrong also because the method itself is not template.

So there is no definition of template function fill_vector and the compiler issues an error.

Comment: Could fill_vector not be a static method? (In which case a call would need to be prefixed with `miniVector<someType>::`, I believe).

Comment: @Peter Schneider It can be a non-static method. We do not know how it actually declared. But in this case its definition is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
int miniVector<T>::fill_vector(miniVector<T> &obj)
```

This says: a method of a class miniVector of type T, that returns an int and takes in a reference to a miniVector object of type T.

You cannot call this as you have, using

```
sizearray = fill_vector<int>(v);
```

You would have to call it like this:

```
sizearray = v.fill_vector(some_other_miniVector);
```

where

`some_other_miniVector` is

```
miniVector<int> some_other_miniVector;
```